# Which maneuvering speeds are included in the TCDS?

Tags: faa-regulations, aircraft-performance, airspeed

I've been looking at the data found in various type certificate data sheets and found something that is a bit ambiguous. In reading a TCDS (like [this one](http://rgl.faa.gov/Regulatory_and_Guidance_Library/rgMakeModel.nsf/0/e0f48f814ea3dd6486257bb20063ad44/$FILE/2A13_Rev_52.pdf), for example) in the "airspeed limits" section it lists the maneuvering speed. But they don't make it clear whether they are referencing the design maneuvering speed (Va) or the Maximum operating maneuvering speed (Vo).

Can anyone clarify which one they are referencing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The speeds that they list in your linked TCDS (along with their corresponding V speeds) are:

- Never exceed 171 mph (148 knots) CAS - V<sub>NE</sub>
- Maximum structural cruising 140 mph (121 knots) CAS - V<sub>NO</sub>
- Maneuvering 129 mph (112 knots) CAS - V<sub>A</sub>
- Flaps Extended 115 mph (100 knots) CAS V<sub>FE</sub>

For a list of these V Speeds along with their definitions, see [14 CFR 1.2](http://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?c=ecfr&SID=f553dbb9c06409a040f3d6865e435c70&rgn=div8&view=text&node=14:1.0.1.1.1.0.1.2&idno=14;cc=ecfr)